# simple responsive bar chart in Jquery , implement in mvc 5 application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to create a Jquery responsive bar chart using the results of a JSon action method in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many JS chart libraries out on the Internet that take JSON data. For example this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/) which is also responsive as you will see in the demo.

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' millions'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor || '#FFFFFF'),
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 1900',
                data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 2008',
                data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: this plugin is free to use for live application??

Comment: That would depend on the type of your application. Check out there documentation and see if it fits. You can use D3 or Flot charts as well.